# Walter Rudin's Functional analysis, theorem 1.18 (c) to (d)

Tags: functional-analysis

$f$ is a linear functional on a topological vector space $X$. Assume $f$ is not a zero map. Then using (c) the null space of $f$ $N(f)$ is not dense in $X$. we can prove (d) $f$ is bounded in some neighborhood $V$ of $0$.
The proof is stated as follows: Assume (c) holds, then $N(f)$ has nonempty exterior. Which means $$ (x+V) \cap N(f) = \emptyset. $$ for some $x \in X$ and some balanced neighborhood $V$ of $0$. Then $f(V)$ is a balanced subset of the scalar field $K$.
Case1: $f(V)$ is bounded. Proved.
Case2: $f(V)=K$. Then there exists $y\in V$ such that $f(y) = -f(x)$, so $x+y\in N(f)$. A contradiction.

I wonder that the contradiction process in case 2 also applied to case 1. Because I think the process just uses balanced condition of $f(V)$. What is wrong?

Comment: The argument that leads to a contradiction doesn't work in case 1. The point is, that $f(V)\cap \{f(x)\}$ can be empty if $f(V)$ is bounded. In this case you cannot choose a $y\in V$ as in case 2.